# How do i change the date format to UK in Excel 2011

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook, microsoft-excel-2011

My Excel 2011 for Macbook will accept input of dates only in US format MM/DD/YY. I would like to enter dates in UK format DD/MM/YY.

Answer (score 2):

In System Preferences, ensure your country is set to United Kingdom in "Language & Region". Then close Excel if it's running, run it, and try again.